# How to call method by var value

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I have some int var:

```
int i = 5
```

and 3 methods:

```
public Method1(){}
public Method2(){}
public Method3(){}
```

How I can call one of this method using his name + variable i?
Something like this:

```
Method4()
{
   Method+i();
}
```

Comment: That isn't a syntax that you can use in C#

Comment: You can't. You could use Reflection to get the method by name, but that would be expensive, slow and most likely confusing for no good reason.

Comment: Lol....what do you even want to do?

Comment: You can definitely do this. You need to use reflection. Wether the "performance" is good enough would depend. Reflection is often "fast enough" but less efficient than just calling the method.

Comment: case statements? if else ? switch? try looking into that it more advisable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do what you asked for with reflection, but that's really ugly.

What you could do is have them all in a list or array and then access them by index:

```
var methods = new Action[]{ null, Method1, Method2, Method3 }; 

methods[1](); // this would call Method1, since Method1 is in position 1 of your array.
```

Comment: And this would probably I guess can be written in a `for-loop`. Instead of doing `methods[1]` .Right?

Comment: Sure, you could access the array any way you would normally access an array. Constant, variable, in a loop, with a for-each loop (watch the null then, maybe it's better to leave it out and have your index not conform to the actual number).

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (i == 3)
                Method3();
```